# Angular Jr init ng-model default value error

Tags: python, angularjs, django

Please help me... this is my script

```
$scope.selected = "{{ mission.name }}";
```

all I want here is to show my value. but it gives the angular js ng-model default value.

```
<input type="text"
                    ng-model="selected"
                    name="{{ field.name }}"
                    value="{{ mission.id }}"
                    typeahead="mission as mission.id for mission in missionNameList">
```

My purpose here is to show {{ mission.id }} as the initial value.

This is actually my plan here. I created a typeahead function wherein the user will select a Mission Name but the thing that will save to the database is the mission ID. so what I did I created 2 textboxes, one will input name and the other one will input the ID and I hide it. such as this:

```
            <input type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    ng-model="selected"
                    typeahead="mission as mission.name for mission in missionNameList | filter:{name:$viewValue} | limitTo:8"
                    value="{{ mission.name }}">
                    {{ field.mission_id }}

            <input type="text"
                    style="display:none"
                    ng-model="selected"
                    name="{{ field.name }}"
                    value="{{ mission.id }}"
                    typeahead="mission as mission.id for mission in missionNameList">
```

Comment: remove curly braces in controller for scope value.. curly braces is for evautation of expression. just replace with $scope.selected = mission.name

Comment: And in your html remove `value` attribute.

Comment: Thanks. it works however my typeahead function did not work when I delete the curly braces

Comment: I updated my question. Thank you so much guys